# Retrieve raster cell values in qfield

Tags: raster, qfield, identify

Is there a way to retrieve raster cell values in qfield (Android version 2.7.6). Similar to the identify tool in qgis or arcgis?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use that value to fill a field in attribute table? If yes, you can use raster_value in a expression https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#raster-value

Comment: I need the information as secondary information, more precisely as a basis for deciding how to draw and attribute my vector in the field. It is a continuous raster (nDSM) and I need accurate information about the cell values. So a symbolization is not sufficient for my needs. I need to retrieve the values in the app when I am out in the field (in the woods).